# How do I prevent deletion if related data still exists?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to make sure that my users can only delete their "question" if all "answers" to that question have already been deleted.

Questions and answers are stored in different collections. Here is some invalid code that explains what I'm looking for:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /questions/{question_id} {
      allow delete: if !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/answers/{answer}).where(answer.question_id == question_id);
    }
  }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to restrict the "exists" call to only those that are answers to the question.

I am open to all suggestions, even those that involve restructuring my data if necessary.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't perform queries against collection using Firebase security rules.  You can only `get()` and check `exists()` of single documents when you know the full ID of that document.  So, what you're trying to do right now isn't possible.

What you can do instead is maintain a count or boolean flag in some other known document, and allow deletion when that count is the value indicates the condition by which the user is allowed to delete the document.