# FLUTTER, SQFLITE ,How do I prevent deletion if related data still exists?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Hi guys I'm newbie in Flutter and currently having intern.

So I got 3 tables here, which are Item database is the main , group database, category database.

If the items databases is using the group, how should I prevent user delete group database because the group is in used in item database?

Will be great if someone can guide on me , because I'm totally new to this and because of intern I had to done it quickly..

```
 import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:ezystock/model/item_model.dart';
import 'package:ezystock/model/group_model.dart';
import 'package:ezystock/model/category_model.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Database _db;
  static const String DB_NAME = 'database.db';

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
  }

  initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, DB_NAME);
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return db;
  }

  _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute("CREATE TABLE 'item' ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'code' TEXT, 'description' TEXT,'cost' REAL,'price' REAL,'category' TEXT,'group' TEXT)");
    await db.execute("CREATE TABLE 'group' ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'code' TEXT, 'description' TEXT)");
    await db.execute("CREATE TABLE 'category' ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'code' TEXT, 'description' TEXT)");
  }

//Category
  Future<Category> saveCategory(Category category) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    category.id = await dbClient.insert("category", category.toMap());
    return category;
  }

  Future<List<Category>> getCategory() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> maps = await dbClient.query("category", columns: ["id", "code","description"]);
    //List<Map> maps = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $TABLE");
    List<Category> category = [];
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        category.add(Category.fromMap(maps[i]));
      }
    }
    return category;
  }

  Future<int> deleteCategory(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.delete("category", where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<int> updateCategory(Category category) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.update("category", category.toMap(),
        where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [category.id]);
  }


  //Group
  Future<Group> saveGroups(Group group) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    group.id = await dbClient.insert("group", group.toMap());
    return group;
  }

  Future<List<Group>> getGroups() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> maps = await dbClient.query("group", columns: ["id", "code","description"]);
    //List<Map> maps = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $TABLE");
    List<Group> groups = [];
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        groups.add(Group.fromMap(maps[i]));
      }
    }
    return groups;
  }

  Future<int> deleteGroups(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> items = await dbClient.query("item", where: 'group = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
    if (items.length > 0) {
      return await dbClient.delete("group", where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
    } else {

    }
  }

  Future<int> updateGroups(Group group) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.update("group", group.toMap(),
        where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [group.id]);
  }




  //items
  Future<Items> saveItems(Items items) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    items.id = await dbClient.insert("item", items.toMap());
    return items;
  }

  Future<List<Items>> getItems() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> maps = await dbClient.query("item", columns: ["id", "code","description","cost","price","category","group"]);
    //List<Map> maps = await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $TABLE");
    List<Items> groups = [];
    if (maps.length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        groups.add(Items.fromMap(maps[i]));
      }
    }
    return groups;
  }

  Future<int> deleteItems(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.delete("item", where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<int> updateItems(Items items) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.update("item", items.toMap(),
        where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [items.id]);
  }

  Future close() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    dbClient.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent deletion if related data still exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56331267/how-do-i-prevent-deletion-if-related-data-still-exists)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56464953/flutter-sqflite-one-to-many-relationship-setup — do FKs help here?

Comment: Nopeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: What happen when you use your code? How did you structure your db?

Comment: @kozubi, I will upload my whole database code above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: dont provide any method to delete `group` table.
So remove this code:

```
  Future<int> deleteGroups(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> items = await dbClient.query("item", where: 'group = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
    if (items.length > 0) {
      return await dbClient.delete("group", where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
    } else {

    }
```

Comment: I want to delete the group that didn't use in item database, but I don't want to delete the group is in used in item database